# How to add path with dots in CreateObject Argument

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to import the path from my component, but one folders has multiple dots, like `board.event.calendar`. Since this is the regular structure in this code base, I just can't change the folder name. I have tried multiple ways to achieve the right path in CreatObject argument, such as:

```
<cfset Event = CreateObject("Component", "path.to.'board.event.calendar'.Event") />
<cfset Event = CreateObject("Component", "path/to/'board.event.calendar'/Event") />
<cfset Event = CreateObject("Component", "path\to\'board.event.calendar'\Event") />
<cfset Event = CreateObject("Component", "path.to.board#chr(046)#event#chr(046)#calendar.Event") />
```

But no luck so far. How can I manage that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateObject()` uses the period character as the separator in your path, and will not accept invalid characters such as the single quote (as in your example above).

One way to do this is to create a mapping, and then use that in your path. For example, if the path to your application is `C:\dev\myapp\`, and the path to your calendar CFCs are in `C:\dev\myapp\calendar\`, then you can create a mapping in your `application.cfc` file like this:

```
this.mappings = {
    "/app": "C:/dev/myapp/",
    "/calendar: "C:/dev/myapp/calendar/"
}
```

(You can also create mappings in the CF Administrator)

And then when creating your component, you could use either:

```
myComponent = createObject("app.calendar.event").init();
```

or

```
myComponent = createObject("calendar.event").init();
```

Comment: Darn, too slow ;-) Assuming a recent version, you can also use the newer syntax instead of `createObject()`, ex. `myComponent = new Calendar.Event()`.

Comment: Although it's true that there were significant performance issues with createObject() back in the MX days, createObject() is no longer a performance problem AFAIK. In terms of creating objects using the `new` syntax, that will not always work. The first problem is that CF needs to know what a `Calendar` object is, which still determined from a mapping. The second issue, which may or may not be an issue, is that the `new` syntax will automatically call the init() method (if defined), and if your code needs to pass anything specifically into the init() method, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: Are you saying some mappings *would* work with createObject, but not `new`? Could you give an example? Haven't run into that one yet, but mappings are an odd beast so wouldn't be surprised....  Now sure what you mean about init(). If you need to pass in some values, why wouldn't `new Calendar.Event(stuff1=111, stuff2=222)` work?

Comment: Ok, I believe you’re right... I haven’t used that syntax. My guess is that both of these syntaxes will evaluate to the same Java code. I kinda like your way... I might have to start doing that.

Comment: I only started using it recently myself.  So far I like it. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking something :)

Comment: @Ageax, I can't find a way to create the component using the new syntax WITHOUT it calling the init() method. I've got some components that have public methods that don't require initialization.